# Two listviews with highlighted selected items

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I've encountered a problem with the back-color of highlighted items in my listviews.
By default its white-gray, and this is bad, because its hard to spot.
So, I wrote a small code :

```
private void lv1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (lv2.HasSelected())
   {
       foreach (ListViewItem item in lv2.SelectedItems)
       {
           item.BackColor = Color.Red;
           item.ForeColor = Color.Red;
       }
   }
}
```

Of course I have set the HideSelection option to false in listview1 and listview2.
This code changes back-colors of items only when listview2 is selected, but I need to do this when a user chooses columns from listview1. Can someone help me??

EDIT:
I missed some details - so, I have 2 listviews and the user is first working with one (second listview) and after this the user is working with the first listview.Now I need to highlight the selected items in the second listview when the user is working in the first listview.

Comment: `Chooses columns from listview1` is a bit confusing. Could you make your question a bit more clear (like really, delete all text and type your question again after telling what you have now and what you want to have instead)? Screenshot would be amazing to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a `ListView`, if a row is selected, the `BackColor` and `ForeColor` are ignored. Selected rows always use the colors designated by the current system theme.

If you want to be able to specify the colours of selected rows, you will have to use [ObjectListView](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html) or a commercial ListView-type control.